# What are the crate drop rates in Surviv.io?

Tags: surviv.io

I want to know what the crate drop percentages in surviv.io are. There are no other surviv questions on this website, and I can't find anything elsewhere. Does anyone know from experience or a website that I have not found? Thanks!

Comment: huh a year later some random person  downvotes lol

Answer (score 1):

https://survivio.fandom.com/wiki/Crates
https://survivio.fandom.com/wiki/Loot_Tiers

Sorry it's not in percentage form, but this is all I can really find. As a rule of thumb, the weaker, the more common. The AWM-S is the rarest gun I believe, I've gotten it 0 times, and the PKP second (1x), the m249 3rd (3x).

Comment: I am not accepting this, as I need percentages, and everything here is common knowledge that I already saw. Thanks for trying to help!